# App submission to itunes connect adding notes/login-details for reviewers?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, submission

I just uploaded an app that uses an external restaurant booking provider. This provider has only enabled one restaurant for testing purposes. Now how do I include this information to apple reviewers so they can test using this restaurant?

The provider will only enable all the restaurants for booking once the app is live.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Apple's submission policies rather than programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you upload either a new app or an update to an app using the interface in iTunes Connect, there is a section as part of this process called `Review Notes`.

This is a regular textbox and is the right place for you to post this information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you know if that is also possible by uploading the app using xcode organizer (after doing archive). It seems that is not there. Thanks